# Not able to Shutdown ubuntu

Tags: shutdown

I am having one more problem in my ubuntu, whenever i try to shutdown ubuntu, shutdown process seems to be started, After 4 dots, system gets hanged and forcefully i keep press power to switchoff my system. I am able to restart and Logout properly, this is since my first installation of the ubuntu

Ubuntu 14.04.1 version &

I am having Laptop of Hp (Ubuntu is working parallel with Windows 8)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sudo poweroff` works well

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and enter

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

This should shutdown your PC, then restart and use the shutdown button (top right menu) to try and shutdown.

Tell me if it works